# Has Shimano produced Ultegra 600 Hub Set, 32 hole?

Tags: shimano, hub

I found this item at an online shop, but can not find infomation about this product. Anyone knows this hub set? and any review infomation available there?

Comment: Google gives at least a half-dozen hits, so presumably there is/was such a thing.

Comment: Indeed. There's one on eBay right now. http://compare.ebay.co.uk/like/321017244018?var=lv&ltyp=AllFixedPriceItemTypes&var=sbar&cbt=y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert on Shimano components, but according to [Sheldon Brown](http://sheldonbrown.com/shimano.html) and [Velobase](http://velobase.com/ListComponents.aspx?SearchID=80683781-cd30-4bd5-a1c5-242358910b6b), there were many 32H hubs from the Shimano 600 series: "Shimano added the word 'Ultegra' to their 600 group set in 1988 with the introduction of the 6400 series groupset. Also often recognized by the tri-color stripe on many of the parts."

According to Velobase, [this is a 32H Shimano 600 Ultegra hub](http://velobase.com/ViewComponent.aspx?ID=1E5F0209-4650-4284-B009-14E4658367FA&Enum=110&AbsPos=64). I'm not sure if that is what you are looking for. [Here is another](http://velobase.com/ViewComponent.aspx?ID=AC8D3B5A-AE8D-4DCB-AB65-DC1AEBE1F598&Enum=110&AbsPos=65).